# Cleaning multiple build directories

Tags: python, git, make

I'm cleaning build directories produced by GNOME build tool, [JHBuild](http://live.gnome.org/Jhbuild). This tool either downloads tarballs or clones git repositories, depending on set-up. After that, it proceeds to compilation (and then installation). Once in a while, something gets screwed up, and I need to clean the build directories so that I can start from scratch (because I don't know how to fix some of these problems).

Here's how I did it, and I'd like you to tell me if it can be improved:

```
import os
import subprocess

top_level = os.path.expanduser("~/src/gnome")
for filename in os.listdir(top_level):
    full_path = "{}/{}".format(top_level, filename)
    if os.path.isdir(full_path):
        cmd = "cd ~/src/gnome/{} && git clean -dfx".format(filename)
        if subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True) != 0:
            cmd = "cd ~/src/gnome/{} && make distclean".format(filename)
            if subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True) != 0:
                cmd = "cd ~/src/gnome/{} && make clean".format(filename)
                subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
full_path = "{}/{}".format(top_level, filename)
```

You can use `os.path.join(top_level, filename)` for that. That way it will also work on any system which does not use `/` as a directory separator (that's not really a realistic concern in this case, but using `os.path.join` doesn't cost you anything and is a good practice to get used to).

```
cmd = "cd ~/src/gnome/{} && git clean -dfx".format(filename)
```

First of all spelling out `~/src/gnome` again is bad practice. This way if you want to change it to a different directory you have to change it in all 4 places. You already have it in the `top_level` variable, so you should use that variable everywhere.

On second thought you should actually not use `top_level` here, because what you're doing here is you're joining `top_level` and `filename`. However you already did that with `full_path`. So you should just use `full_path` here.

You should also consider using `os.chdir` instead of `cd` in the shell. This way you only have to change the directory once per iteration instead of on every call. I.e. you can just do:

```
if os.path.isdir(full_path):
    os.chdir(full_path)
    if subprocess.call("git clean -dfx", shell=True) != 0: 
        if subprocess.call("make distclean", shell=True) != 0:
            subprocess.call("make clean", shell=True)
```

(Note that since `full_path` is an absolute path, it doesn't matter that you don't `chdir` back at the end of each iteration.)

Another good habit to get into is to not use `shell=True`, but instead pass in a list with command and the arguments, e.g. `subprocess.call(["make", "clean"])`. It doesn't make a difference in this case, but in cases where your parameters may contain spaces, it saves you the trouble of escaping them.

Comment: Regarding your very last comment, I'm tempted to change the subprocess to something like `subprocess.call("git clean -dfx".split())`. Is that kool?

Comment: @Tshepang: The point of passing in an array instead of `shell=True` is that it will handle arguments with spaces or shell-metacharacters automatically correctly without you having to worry about. Using `split` circumvents this again (as far as spaces are concerned anyway), so there's little point in that. Since in this case you know that your arguments don't contain any funny characters, you can just keep using `shell=True` if you don't want to pass in a spelled-out array.

Comment: In such cases, won't [shlex.split()](http:///doc.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) be useful?

Comment: @Tshepang: I don't see how. If you already know the arguments, `subprocess.call(shlex.split('some_command "some filename"'))` buys you nothing over `subprocess.call(["some_command", "some filename"]` and IMHO has a higher chance that you might forget the quotes. However if the filename is inside a variable, `subprocess.call(["some_comand", filename])` still works no matter which special characters `filename` contains, while using `shlex.split` would require you to somehow escape the contents of `filename` first, in which case you could have just used `shell=True` in the first place.